# Backups - Operation Unsupported

Tags: 14.04, backup

I am trying to back-up my /home/ folder to my FTP server using the backups program that is pre-installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 system, however after 5 minutes of clicking 'Backup now', I get an error message stating 'Operation Unsupported'.

Does anyone know a fix to this?

Comment: I tried your solution to back up locally then back up via ftp again and it didn't work for me. I submitted a bug report to the dev: https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1396691 Hopefully anyone else finding your post and having a hard time, will be able to add their info to my bug report to help the dev or at least log in to Launchpad and click "This bug also affects me."

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome this problem by making a backup locally to an external hard drive. After making this backup I was able to backup remotely without any problems.